# Tomcat Custom Error Servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a custom error handling servlet which catch all throwables :

```
    <error-page>
      <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
      <location>/Exception</location>
    </error-page>
```

The thing is, this servlet will do the forward request of the resolution and set some custom response headers. I want it to also set the http status code appropriately but it seems like if I set the http status code to the response, then I call forward, the response code automatically goes to 500.

why?

Comment: Please add how are you overiding  status in java code

Comment: Just a plain response.setStatus(xxxx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to  abide proper response code to Throwables then I think 500  is appropriate.

> 500 Internal Server Error
>       A generic error message, given when an unexpected condition was encountered and no more specific message is suitable.

if you intentionally want to abide something else then you can do it with below:

```
response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
```

or

```
response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN );
```

I mean you can give any desired format.

Comment: I would like the exception servlet to attach some additional information to the headers and also write some generic content